# How select rows with no matching entry in another table even one of table is empty

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables like this :

Table **sharet:**
with column

```
id
user
blocked
texte
time_add
```

Table **sondage**
with column

```
id
qst
respons
user
time_add
```

I want get the contents of two table. But whe i use Left Joint, it give nothing, because one of the the table is empty, How can i resolve it?? I want get the contents of all table even one of it is empty!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming that  the relation between the two tables is based  on user column 
then if you don't know wichh of the table is empty but want retrive in anyway the result 
you could use a union  between the inverted  join

```
  select sharet.*, sondage.*
  from sharet
  left join sondage on sondage.user = sharet.user 
  UNION
  select sharet.*, sondage.*
  from sondage
  left join sharet on sondage.user = sharet.user
```

On using an union between the inner join for the two table and the left join of the not matching row between both the tables

```
  select sharet.*, sondage.*
  from sharet
  inner join sondage on sondage.user = sharet.user 
  UNION
  select sharet.*, sondage.*
  from sharet
  left join sondage on sondage.user = sharet.user and sharet.user is null
  UNION
  select sharet.*, sondage.*
  from sondage
  left join sharet on sondage.user = sharet.user   and sondage.user is null
```

Comment: Hi **scaisEdge**, the rule you give work fine when the rows numbers is equals from two table, if is not, ti t give me more result. How resolve it!!!